# Woocommerce Minimum Order by User Role

Tags: php, function, woocommerce

Somebody previously asked a question similar to mine, but the solutions offered do not seem to help me.

I am working on a wholesale website. For first time buyers, the minimum order is $500. For returning buyers / reorders there is no minimum. I am assuming I need to make 2 different wholesale user roles - one for first time buyers and the other for returning / reorder buyers. I was thinking Wholesale New and Wholesale Reorder would work. How do I apply this to the functions.php? This is the code I am currently using:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' , 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );

function wc_minimum_order_amount() {
// Set this variable to specify a minimum order value
$minimum = 500;

if ( WC()->cart->total < $minimum ) {

    if( is_cart() ) {

        wc_print_notice( 
            sprintf( 'You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order, your current order total is %s.' , 
                wc_price( $minimum ), 
                wc_price( WC()->cart->total )
            ), 'error' 
        );

    } else {

        wc_add_notice( 
            sprintf( 'You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order, your current order total is %s.' , 
                wc_price( $minimum ), 
                wc_price( WC()->cart->total )
            ), 'error' 
        );

    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need [`current_user_can()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) to test the current user's capability to do something.

### Create a Role

First, you would need to create a new role for users who don't have any restrictions. The [Members](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/) plugin is genius for creating roles and editing their capabilities.

For example, you could create a `Returning Wholesaler` role.

### Define the new Role's capabilities

You should duplicate the "Customer" role's capabilities... so `read` , `edit_posts`, and `delete_posts`.

And then, add a new capability called `wholesale_reorder`

### Modify your conditional logic

Then you can convert your if statement from:

```
if ( WC()->cart->total < $minimum )
```

to:

```
if ( WC()->cart->total < $minimum && ! current_user_can( 'wholesale_reorder' ) )
```

### Simplification in the case of no new roles

If you don't have any existing customers, don't need multiple levels of wholesale, don't have wholesale in conjunction with regular customers, *and* you don't have a way to register without ordering, then ostensibly you could skip adding new roles and just test `current_user_can('customer')` as the only people who would be customers would be those who have ordered something already.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much! You are a life saver.

Comment: If this worked, don't forget to mark it as the answer.